# VSCode - Break on "Uncaught exceptions" checkbox hidden

Tags: visual-studio-code, debug

I used to see a checkbox named "Uncaught Exceptions" in the VSCode Debug sidebar, under the "Breakpoints" section, just like in this pict (look bottom left of the picture)

[image: Debug Image]

But I don't see it anymore, and I don't remember when it disapeared. I am using VSCode 1.37.1 at the moment.

Is there a new setting to show/hide this?

Comment: You are apparently debugging a TypeScript program. Are you sure that this language supports exception breakpoints?

Comment: The screenshot I provided was not mine, but one that can be found on code.visualstudio.com. It is just meant to show the checkbox I used to see in my instance of VSCode.

But to address your concern about TypeScript supporting exception breakpoints, I believe it does since the checkbox is present in the screenshot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of VS Code always has it when in Debug Mode.

To debug, press the Run in the top of the window, then press Start Debugging. Make sure you have at least one break point on your editor, which you can do by just clicking one of the lines in your code and you'll see the red circle, which pauses the program when that line is reached.

The BREAKPOINTS will appear again on the bottom left.